# Flutter Bottom Sheet Dialog Not Resizing in some cases

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottom-sheet

I have a Custom BottomSheetDilaog in a flutter.

There are two ways this dialog can be open

1)Via Floating Button above Bottom navigation that is attached To HomeMainScreen

2)Via Button on HomeScreen Tab that is the first widget in Bottom navigation.

When a user clicks on the floating button the TextFieldForm Resize as the keyboards open.
But when it is open via HomeScreen Tab Button then Its root view is Resize and not the Bottom sheet Dialog.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    backgroundColor: foreground_color,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.r))),
    context: context,
    builder: (builder) {
      return AnimatedPadding(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        curve: Curves.easeInOutSine,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        child: SafeArea(
          maintainBottomViewPadding: true,
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
```

How to make sure that in both cases it resize as expected when the keyboard is opened.

Sample Code

https://github.com/parmarravi/bottom_sheet_bug

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the whole modal with `SingleChildScrollView` widget?

Comment: @snap In Bottom Sheet Dialog or in Home Screen where the button is there?